# Run executable jar from batch file but with console open so that user can see the output. Not using "java -jar"

Tags: java, batch-file, jar, console, executable-jar

I have created an executable jar file and it works fine on double clicking on it. But there is this need to show output at the end of the execution. I used batch file with `start xxx.jar` command and it executes the jar but **without console and output**. I then used `java -jar XXX.jar` it does the job but the thing here is user may not be having jre installed.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, your question doesn't make sense. In the end, an executable JAR still requires that a JRE is installed. Without a "java" JVM binary on your computer, no JAR can be run. An executable JAR is a normal java JAR, just with some meta information, so that java -jar whatever.jar knows which class has the main() method to run.

Comment: If the jar wont run unless jre is preinstalled, will it work if I create an **.exe** file using some tool like Launch4j? Will it execute if still there is no jre? Thanks for the reply and explanation, it would save much time if i learn the hard way. :)

Comment: Sure, when you are able to turn the jar into a true binary executable ... then you do not need a JVM any more. But I have never used such tools, so I cant say much else.

Comment: If you use JDK14+ you can use `jlink` to create a specific cut-down JRE runtime image for your jar's dependencies and distribute that with your jar, and can also use `jpackage` to make your application into an executable (with or without a console) and package altogether as an installer to deploy to other machines more easily.

Comment: Thanks guys for providing bunch of options. Sure one will workout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`start` will ask windows to launch the file using the default launcher configured in your registry.

This, naturally, means nothing happens / an error occurs unless you've got a bizarre situation where the end user has actually installed a JVM, which you should not be relying on, and you'd have absolutely no idea whose JVM that is, or what version it is, or if it has been properly maintained. It will also use `javaw.exe` which is the one that doesn't show a console, and there is absolutely nothing you can do to change this.

I think you're misinformed - you want a solution that works if:

- The user has installed a JDK or (obsolete) JRE themselves, and installed it in a way that double clicking jar files actually works, but...
- did not update the PATH variable or otherwise ensured that `java` on the command line works

I don't think that covers many installations at all. The vast majority of deployments will either be 'the user did not install any java', in which case neither `start` nor `java -jar` is going to be a solution, or they installed it with java on the path, in which case `java -jar` in a batch file works fine.

### Okay so how DO you deploy java apps

In modern times? With jlink to create a cut-down executable, and then you write your own installer which installs a JVM that you trust (the one jlink made, which is smaller, as all bits you don't need for the app in question aren't included in it), and thus results in the user being able to run your app without the need to 'find a java installation and install it'. This is unfortunately more difficult than it could be and requires that you use the module system.

### Sounds like too much work, what's wrong with the old way?

The concept of the JRE (a java virtual machine that can run java applications, but without any development tools included) is **dead**. There is no more JRE; java8, now 7 years old, was the last time that was a thing, and the JRE that oracle ships is pretty much out of time: They have stopped supporting it, or will real soon now. That means **you are asking your users to install software that will no longer receive security updates**. That's why it's such a bad idea to do it like this. Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.

Comment: I believe `jlink` is the answer I was looking for. Thanks for your detailed explanation and the exact suggestion.It helped alot.

Comment: One small correction, "It will also use javaw.exe which is the one that doesn't show a console, and there is absolutely nothing you can do to change this." On windows this is not strictly true, you could edit the registry and make it use java.exe instead of javaw.exe. Not sure about other platforms.

Comment: @SephB it would excruciatingly bad form to use regedit.exe within a batch file to _mess with the user's registry_ like that.

Comment: @rzwitserloot agreed. I was only correcting the `absolutely nothing` part. You can do it, but probably don't want to.